# Download FRED data by month

Tags: r

I am trying to download FRED data by month. Is there any way that I can download data by month instead of day? Thanks in advance.

```
getSymbols("GOLDPMGBD228NLBM", src = "FRED")
```

Comment: ...aggregate???

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you want end-of-month values:

### Quantmod

You can download the data as usual, then use the `period.apply`, `endpoints`, and `last` functions to get the last observation for each month:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("GOLDPMGBD228NLBM", src = "FRED")
x <- na.omit(GOLDPMGBD228NLBM)
eom_quantmod <- period.apply(x, endpoints(x, on = "months"), last)
```

### FredR

You can also download data using the FredR package: https://github.com/jcizel/FredR

```
library(FredR)
key <- "your_fred_api_key"
fred <- FredR(key)
eom_fredr <- fred$series.observations(
  series_id = "GOLDPMGBD228NLBM",
  frequency = "m",
  aggregation_method = "eop")
```

We get the same values in both cases:

```
tail(eom_quantmod); tail(eom_fredr[, c("date", "value")])
#            GOLDPMGBD228NLBM
# 2016-08-31          1309.25
# 2016-09-30          1322.50
# 2016-10-31          1272.00
# 2016-11-30          1178.10
# 2016-12-29          1145.90
# 2017-01-06          1175.85
#          date    value
# 1: 2016-08-01 1309.250
# 2: 2016-09-01 1322.500
# 3: 2016-10-01 1272.000
# 4: 2016-11-01 1178.100
# 5: 2016-12-01 1145.900
# 6: 2017-01-01        .
```